# Trouble with headset microphones on Xbox One in multiplayer

Tags: xbox-one, voice-chat

My boyfriend and I are trying to stream on Twitch using my Xbox One console. We're having trouble with the microphones on either of our headsets. Alone and on either of my two controllers, they work perfect. As soon as we start using the two controllers/headsets together (in party chat), the microphone on the primary signed in person's headset is muted or automatically set to a very very low volume, even though the settings for both microphones show they're on maximum volume/output. We don't know how to fix this, and we've tested both headsets on both controllers individually, so we know it's gotta be some sort of setting we're missing. Both controllers are up to date.  This also happens for any games we play (though we've been spending most of our time on Halo 5 and Minecraft). Does anyone know what might be going on? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Reason for downvote? AFAIK this is on topic

Comment: Check settings, sound, chat mixer.

Comment: Are you snapped when it happened?

Comment: Can you verify that not only the controllers but also the headsets are up-to-date? You can check by having them plugged in when updating your peripherals.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that no one in the party is hearing the microphone input?  I ask this because party chat purposely does not allow microphone communication between two players who are playing locally together.  This is to prevent an annoying feedback loop.  When my wife and I are both in a party together with two profiles and two controller/headset combos, all of the non-local party members hear us both fine, but we cannot hear each other.  I imagine that this set-up could negatively affect how the microphones pick up chat for Twitch.